# Book on (finite) Groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory, book-recommendation

I almost got a Math degree but want to learn better topics in group theory, expecially about finite ones. I studied just introductions on groups (in the firsts algebra courses) and something about group actions and theory of characters. Could anyone recommend a good book on the topic? Thank you

Comment: Bertram Huppert's *Endliche Gruppen* may be suitable for you to learn finite groups. This book covers many topics in finite groups thoroughly, but is also a bit too long if you want to learn in a short period.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check the index.

Comment: *Introduction to the Theory of Finite Groups* by Walter Ledermann.

Comment: Rotman's *Introduction to Finite Groups* is really great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Elements of Abstract Algebra** by Allan Clark
[Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486647250)

**Theory of Groups of Finite Order** by William Burnside
[Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1375636391)

**A Course on Group Theory** by H.E. Rose
[Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848828888)

In German Edition:
Endliche Gruppen I and II by Bertram Huppert
Algebra: Gruppen - Ringe - Körper by Karpfinger

Comment: I think the book by Burnside is a terrible suggestion. It is simply too old to be useful for anyone who actually wants to learn group theory. It is a nice thing to read for the history, but way too much has happened to the way we think about these things for the actual material to be a good starting point for anyone now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

**Contemporary Abstract Algebra** by Joseph A Gallian

[Link](http://www.cengage.com/c/contemporary-abstract-algebra-9e-gallian)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* is a good place to start. I also really like Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, though this is primarily a first year graduate text, so it may be a bit terse in some places.

Answer (score 0):

For the representation theory of finite groups, I suggest Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*.